# How to add a 'c' wire common wire to this system

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

I have a galaxy cast iron gas boiler and i'm trying to determine where to attach the 'c' wire on the furnace for my new wifi thermostat.  The cable is an 18/5 but is only using 2 of 5 wires currently.  Based on other threads i've read it sounds like i can use one of the available wires for a 'c'.

I have attached a photo of where the thermostat wire connects to the furnace (A).

I'm not that familiar with thermostat wiring and i've tried to label the picture based on what is see on the furnace.  (TH or TR)

thermostat Rh = TH2
thermostat W1 = TH1 (White Wire)

[image]

[image]

Comment: A picture of the current thermostat wiring would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the second image, I'd say `TR2` should be connected to the `C` terminal. However, for this to work, you'll likely have to swap `TH1` and `TH2`. Since `TR1` is associated with `TH1`, `TH1` should be the `R` wire while `TH2` should be the `W` wire.

The complete circuit should be:
`TR1` -> `TH1` -> `R` on thermostat -> `W` on thermostat -> `TH2` -> `TR2`.

Then you can connect a wire from `TR2` to the `C` terminal on the thermostat.

***NOTE:*** If the transformer is not sized to support the additional load of the thermostat, you could end up blowing a fuse or frying the transformer.